# I got Argument labels '_:, withBlock, withCancel:)' do not match any available overloads. Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Swift 3, I'm getting a build error:

`Argument labels '_:, withBlock, withCancel:)' do not match any available overloads`

Code:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(chatPartnerId)
    ref.observeSingleEventOfType.(.value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
    }, withCancel: nil)
```

Comment: You need to look at the method signature for that method to determine the appropriate parameters.  The intellisense should give you an idea

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(chatPartnerId) 

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("Snapshot:", snapshot.value as! String)
    }, withCancel: nil)
```